# Why won't my listIterator.next().toString method for Linked List return a valid String? It thows a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator

I have a simple card game which currently just shuffles a 52 card deck and allows the user to iterate through the linked list containing Card objects with a list iterator. However in this method the listIterator.next().toString() method throws the java.util.ConcurrentModificationException and does not turn into a String. I have included a toString method in the Card class and here is the first part of my code:

```
public void runGame() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean quit = false;                   //var to quit game
    boolean forward = true;                 //var to organise whether going forward or backward

    printMenu();                            //shows user the key bindings

    while (!quit) {
        int action = scanner.nextInt();     //obtains user input
        scanner.nextLine();                 //stops enter key errors
        ListIterator<Card> listIterator = this.cards.listIterator(); //uses a list iterator
        createCardList();
        shuffleCardList();                  //generates random card deck in this.cards linked list

        switch (action) {
            case 0:                         //quits game
                System.out.println("Thanks for playing");
                quit = true;
                break;
            case 1:                         //moves one position forward through list
                if (!forward) {             //if going backwards, sorts duplication error
                    if (listIterator.hasNext()) {
                        listIterator.next();
                    }
                    forward = true;
                }
                if (listIterator.hasNext()) { //goes to next card
                    System.out.println("Next card is " + listIterator.next().toString());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("We have reached the end of the card deck");
                    forward = false;
                }
                break;
```

While the toString  method in the Card class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "{" +
            "suit='" + suit + '\'' +
            ", cardValue='" + cardValue + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

Comment: Try calling `createCardList` and `shuffleCardList` _before_ you call `this.cards.listIterator()`.

Comment: To add on what @Sweeper said, your issue depends on the fact tha you're modifying your collection while iterating it. It should be enough to create the iterator once you shuffled the cards.